# Button not Clickable in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, grid

I have a program which I am adding a button to it, I added it by saying **Content_Grid.Children.Add(grid_Main)** but when I try to click it, it is not click able.

Code Behind:

```
 // Create Grid \\
            Content_Grid.Children.Add(grid_Main);
            grid_Main.Height = MainWindowHeight;
            grid_Main.Width = MainWindowWidth;
            grid_Main.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWin" x:Class="WhackaMoleReal.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="421.378" Width="624.929">
    <Grid x:Name="Content_Grid">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Can You Catch the Mole?" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="85" Width="460" FontFamily="SimHei" FontSize="36" Margin="10,0,0,-27"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="475,0,0,16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="90" Height="42"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You're adding the `grid_Main` "on TOP" (in Z-Index) of the button and textblock. That's why you're not able to click the button. It's actually being hidden behind the other grid

Comment: Also, is there any reason that you're mixing adding controls in XAML AND the code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, all I did was add a grid in the XAML, and got rid of the one made in the code behind.